Why am i getting "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." although i have it initialized and configured it correctly?
TLDR: Last paragraph explains highlighted issues!
My project partners have succesfully connected their databases with one another and have created tables in MSSQL that do show up for one another. However in my server they wont connect nor show up even when i add migrations. The code, configurations and syntax must be correct considering it works for my partners. After trying to run a "add-migrations" and "update-database"; i always get a tall error log with the main issue: ConnectionString is not initialized. I am confused as to why i keep getting this error even though i have initialized it, connected it and even the sql is running. I would highly appreciate any help, Thank you!
** The Appseting.json code:**
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "CRUDS": "server=localhost; database=LabProjekti; Integrated Security=true;TrustserverCertificate=True;"
    },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

The Program.cs (container) code:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BooksContext>(options =>

options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CRUDS")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();

The error log:
PM> add-migration Book
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.


TLDR:
As i mentioned priorly, i am trying to add a migration and update the database. Adding the migration works just fine but my issue is with updating it to the database. Whenever i run the said code i expect it to add new tables in my mssql database but instead i am always getting the same identical errors about how i have not initialized it the connectionString.
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "CRUDS": "server=localhost; database=LabProjekti; Integrated Security=true;TrustserverCertificate=True;"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ **the config highlighted:**
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CRUDS")));
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ **the error highlighted:**
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

